# VB.NET code to Convert shared local path to UNC path

Tags: vb.net, unc, shared-directory

We have `windows 2003` server Pc named pc2 in which local drives are shared with different names. For example local drive E is shared with name 'datapath' so that all users in `network` access that drive using network path '`\\pc2\datapath\'`. We need VB.net code to convert local path to shared `UNC path` i.e if we input 'E:\netuse',code must return '`\\pc2\datapath\netuse'`.

Is there any way to do this in `VB.net` ?

EDIT:
Drive E is not mapped,it is just shared

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code worked very well

```
        Dim SharePath As String = "e:\Netuse"
        Dim SplitPath() As String = Split(SharePath, "\")
        Dim CurrentPath As String = String.Empty
        Dim ShareName As String = String.Empty
        Dim CurrentFolderIndex As Integer
        Dim UNCPath As String = String.Empty

        For CurrentFolderIndex = 0 To SplitPath.GetUpperBound(0)
            If CurrentPath = String.Empty Then
                CurrentPath = String.Concat(SplitPath(CurrentFolderIndex), "\\")
            Else
                CurrentPath += String.Concat(SplitPath(CurrentFolderIndex), "\\")
            End If
            ShareName = GetShareName(CurrentPath)
            If ShareName <> String.Empty Then
                CurrentFolderIndex += 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        UNCPath = String.Concat("\\", My.Computer.Name, "\", ShareName)

        For SubPathIndex As Integer = CurrentFolderIndex To SplitPath.GetUpperBound(0)
            UNCPath = String.Concat(UNCPath, "\", SplitPath(SubPathIndex))
        Next

        Console.WriteLine(UNCPath)



    Public Function GetShareName(ByVal FolderPath As String) As String

        Dim Searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher(String.Concat("select * from win32_share WHERE Path = '", FolderPath, "'"))
        Dim ShareName As String = String.Empty

        For Each Share As ManagementObject In Searcher.Get()
            ShareName = Share("Name").ToString
        Next

        Return ShareName

    End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

Just created a small app which seems to work.

It takes a textbox with a non-unc value and converts it,then sets a label

Remember to include the following namespaces if you haven't already;

```
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO
```

This is the method that does all the work;

```
Private Function GetUNCPath(ByVal sFilePath As String) As String

Dim allDrives() As DriveInfo = DriveInfo.GetDrives()
Dim d As DriveInfo
Dim DriveType, Ctr As Integer
Dim DriveLtr, UNCName As String
Dim StrBldr As New StringBuilder

If sFilePath.StartsWith("\\") Then Return sFilePath

UNCName = Space(160)
GetUNCPath = ""

DriveLtr = sFilePath.Substring(0, 3)

For Each d In allDrives
  If d.Name = DriveLtr Then
    DriveType = d.DriveType
    Exit For
  End If
Next

If DriveType = 4 Then

  Ctr = WNetGetConnection(sFilePath.Substring(0, 2), UNCName, UNCName.Length)

  If Ctr = 0 Then
    UNCName = UNCName.Trim
    For Ctr = 0 To UNCName.Length - 1
      Dim SingleChar As Char = UNCName(Ctr)
      Dim asciiValue As Integer = Asc(SingleChar)
      If asciiValue > 0 Then
        StrBldr.Append(SingleChar)
      Else
        Exit For
      End If
    Next
    StrBldr.Append(sFilePath.Substring(2))
    GetUNCPath = StrBldr.ToString
  Else
    MsgBox("Cannot Retrieve UNC path" & vbCrLf & "Must Use Mapped Drive of SQLServer", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
  End If
Else
  MsgBox("Cannot Use Local Drive" & vbCrLf & "Must Use Mapped Drive of SQLServer", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
End If

End Function
```

Declare this function;

```
  Declare Function WNetGetConnection Lib "mpr.dll" Alias "WNetGetConnectionA" (ByVal lpszLocalName As String, _
       ByVal lpszRemoteName As String, ByRef cbRemoteName As Integer) As Integer
```

Call the code from a button click;

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
     Dim RealFileName As String = GetUNCPath(txtFileName.Text)
     lblUNC.Text = RealFileName
  End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think drive must be mapped to use above code.As i already mentioned our drive only shared not mapped

Comment: yes just tried..cannot use local drive,must use mapped drive of sql server error came

Comment: I got this message when I mistakenly sent "A::\" as my drive instead of "A:\" (I was generating the string in code) - when I fixed the string, the bewildering reference to sql server went away