# Why do I get path with Drive name when deployed in server?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an application where I have Server.MapPath("\Person\Account")
While I run in debugging mode, the path converts to the network name \\Machine01\Person\Account.

However, if I use the deployed site, it comes up as "C:\Person\Account" while I'm expecting \\WebServer01\Person\Account"

I do lack some core knowledge about paths here. Help required.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.NET code to Convert shared local path to UNC path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16185716/vb-net-code-to-convert-shared-local-path-to-unc-path)

Comment: Answers are not quite what I want. The question you've mentioned has answers as custom code. I would like to know if there is anything in .NET library or some short method without string manipulation.

Comment: I had looked into it a bit before and all i found were these string-manipulations. But since they work fine once you implement them one time i didn't go on looking. If you stumble into something, let me know i'd like to know :)